# How to make image change with hover through javascript only?

Tags: javascript, html, hover

Javascript newbie following Ania Kubow's Javascript bootcamp video / card matching game tutorial (https://youtu.be/Xm4BObh4MhI?t=34702).

I'd like to request some help figuring out how to have an image change when hovered over, specifically within the Javascript code. For context, I'm making a card matching game based on the tutorial above, except it's Pokemon themed. When the card/open Pokeball is hovered over, it should then change to a half-way closed Pokeball to show that it's almost selected.

What's in the HTML file in this section is literally just:

```
            <div class="section2"></div>
```

So it's all in the Javascript where all of this comes from. Here is the main function. (Bolded is what I added myself.

```
    function createBoard() {
        for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; i++) {
        const card = document.createElement('img')
        card.setAttribute('src', 'src/images/pokeballOpen.png')
        card.setAttribute('data-id', i)
        card.addEventListener('click', flipCard)
**        card.addEventListener('mouseover', hoverPokeball)
        card.addEventListener('mouseout', unhoverPokeball)**
        container.appendChild(card)
        }
    }
```

Then I also have:

```
    function hoverPokeball() {
        card.setAttribute('src', 'src/images/pokeballMid.png')
    }

    // unhover over pokeball
    function unhoverPokeball() {
        card.setAttribute('src', 'src/images/pokeballOpen.png')
    }
```

I am 100% missing something simple here, and I would appreciate it if any of you could help me out.

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, please provide them in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions `hoverPokeball` and `unhoverPokeball` are not defined in the same scope as the `card` variable, and can therefore not reference it. I presume you get a `ReferenceError`.

There are multiple ways to reference the (un-)hovered element in its listener:

## Passing the event object

You can **pass [the event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) to the listener** (or rather, expect it). Its [`currentTarget` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) will refer to the respective `card`.

Example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; ++i) {
  const card = document.createElement("img");
  // ...
  card.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverPokeball);
  card.addEventListener("mouseout", unhoverPokeball);
  // ...
}

// ...

function hoverPokeball(event) {
  event.currentTarget/*...*/;
}
function hoverPokeball(event) {
  event.currentTarget/*...*/;
}
```

**Sidenote**:

The `target` property refers to the the target from which the event is dispatched. The `currentTarget` property refers to the currently listening target, often a child of the dispatching target.

In this case, `card` refers to an [empty element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-content-nothing); more specifically, to the [void element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements) `<img>`. Such elements do not have children, so the `currentTarget` and `target` properties will refer to the same target.

You should prefer the `currentTarget` and `target` properties for the concepts of referring to the currently listening target and the dispatching target, respectively.

In this case, we want to refer to `card` (the element to which we added the listener), so we should use the `currentTarget` property. It just so happens that `card` will always be the dispatching target as well due to it being an empty element.

## Passing the reference

Similarly, you can **pass the reference `card`** to the functions. This requires some kind of closure for the specific reference, e.g. by [using an anonymous function defined in the respective iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75955304/13561410) or binding the reference as an argument.

Example of binding as an argument:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; ++i) {
  const card = document.createElement("img");
  // ...
  card.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverPokeball.bind(null, card));
  card.addEventListener("mouseout", unhoverPokeball.bind(null, card));
  // ...
}

// ...

function hoverPokeball(card) {
  // ...
}
function hoverPokeball(card) {
  // ...
}
```

## Using `this` in listeners

In listeners, `this` is bound to refer to the listening target. You can **use `this` for the listening target**, since the respective `card` is that event target.

Example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < cardArray.length; ++i) {
  const card = document.createElement("img");
  // ...
  card.addEventListener("mouseover", hoverPokeball);
  card.addEventListener("mouseout", unhoverPokeball);
  // ...
}

// ...

function hoverPokeball() {
  this/*...*/;
}
function hoverPokeball() {
  this/*...*/;
}
```

**Note**: You cannot bind a `this` context to *arrow function expressions*. This means that `hoverPokeball` and `unhoverPokeball` have to be defined as *function declarations* or *function expressions* for this to work. Read more in [MDN's section about `this` in handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_value_of_this_within_the_handler).

---

Alternatively, you can query for the element in the functions, e.g. by their `data-id` attribute.

Generally, I would recommend to use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation) for a task like this.

Comment: Ah wait new issue -- with this addition into my code, I am able to successfully have the pokeball change images when hovering over them, but this has also impacted clicking them as well. even after clicking on them to reveal the pokemon/card, when i move my mouse again, it reverts back to the original, unhovered stage. Do you have any advice for combining these two aspects together? I can provide my full code if necessary

Comment: @greetingsEarth You can use a (boolean) flag to indicate the card's "flipped" state. When active, that state should prevent the (un-)hover effect to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target` to access the `<img>` element being hovered.

```js
function hoverPokeball(event) {
    event.target.src = 'src/images/pokeballMid.png';
}
function unhoverPokeball(event) {
    event.target.src = 'src/images/pokeballOpen.png';
}
```

Comment: Generally, I would recommend `event.currentTarget` over `event.target`. In this case they just happen to refer to the same target since `<img>` is an empty (void) element.